# RadioButton Text style

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, .net-2.0, radio-button

I have the following markup:

where

```
.checkBoxImg input { vertical-align:top; margin-top:5px;}
```

and

```
this.rbtnAssessedNo.Text = "<img src='images/icons/icon_no.gif' /><span style=\"margin-top:5px; vertical-align:top\">No</span>";
```

I get RadioButtons text which is: img (27x27px) and text: NO(16x16px) on which margin-top:5px doesn't work and it is to hight relative to img. Also when i change vertical-align on it to middle it goes to the bottom of whole RadioButton span which is also wrong.

i'm aiming to get img and text NO that will be in the middle of img (more or less 5px from top will be ok). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you stuck with .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `span` usually are *line dependent* and they are not like div's that are like boxes. So they tent to not keep the margin you set.

Change it to `div` and use `display:inline` and the margin will be set.

Comment: @user1291518 Maybe is work, but it have no place to move, try to warp it all in a div, or give me the page online to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

give your `span` a `line-height` equal to the `height` of the image, in your case 27px

```
"<img src='images/icons/icon_no.gif'/><span style='line-height:27px;'>No</span>"
```